# Where is Voice Privacy on OnePlus phone?

Tags: google-voice, oneplus-one

Can someone give me a step by step on finding the Google Voice privacy on my OnePlus phone?

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify what did you mean by "Voice Privacy"? I admit I didn't have Google Voice, but I didn't find any clue about "Google Voice Privacy" on Google.

Answer (score 1):

Since Voice Privacy is a CDMA network function, and OnePlus One is a GSM phone, there is no such option to be selected. GSM technology doesn't have the same vulnerability as CDMA.